# How can I change the front-end framework used in MVC projects in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

The default is Bootstrap and while it's perfectly fine in its way, I prefer to work with MDL.

Its a bit of a pain to go and strip out Bootstrap from every project and implement MDL instead.

Is there a way I can create a new project template that has MDL setup by default instead of Bootstrap?

Comment: Maybe take a look at Sidewaffle templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your own template with MDL.

[Here you have an article about creating such templates](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/advanced/custom-mvc-templates). It is not directly about template with MDL, but it should not be difficult to add this.

Comment: Thanks very much for this!

Answer (score 1):

You can try **material design with bootstrap**. You dont need to change your markup, just replace the css and and add the related JS file.

See http://mdbootstrap.com/

Comment: My issue with adding in the MDL and not taking the bootstrap out is that the bootstrap will still load anyway slowing down page load... Although now I look at your link, that looks like a decent option, upvote for you!

Comment: There are two articles on how to integrate MDBootstrap to ASP.NET MVC and also ready to use templates. You can find them in the MDBootstrap website, Tools & Resources (last in the menu) and then Articles.